# Use meta data in custom css

Tags: php, css, wordpress, inject

I am modifying a Wordpress theme, and want to add custom field for adding color codes into css. (Note that I am using Advanced Custom Fields)

At the moment I have created custom.php

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css");
$color = get_field('color_code');

?>

.container {
  background: <?php echo $color; ?>;
}
```

Which is loaded in the template as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ; ?>/css/custom.php">
```

The problem is that the custom.php cannot use get_field(), and I believe it's because it has no relation with the current page.

Does anybody know a way to use these custom fields for injection to CSS?

BR / Henric

Comment: The [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I have the need to steer per page. Not only one setting.

Comment: You mean you want to have the `color_code` setting settable for each page?

Comment: Yep, I would like to control specific CSS on all pages.

Comment: That's [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Example_Using_Custom_Fields) -- there's an example and the full documentation.

Comment: Took a step back and added custom CSS in header if custom field was available. Since style should be added there, validation for page will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already enqueuing a stylesheet, you can use [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/108843/12615) and it will add styles just after a enqueued style. In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-style.css' );
    $color = get_field('color_code');
    if( $color ) {
        $custom_css = ".singular .entry-title{ color: $color; }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom', $custom_css );
    }
}, 11 );
```

And `my-style.css`:

```css
.singular .entry-title {
    color:#998F56;
}
```

Prints this if the post has the field `color_code` set:

<kbd>[image: html output]</kbd>

---

Another option is print it by hand, using `wp_head`, which prints it just before the `</head>` tag:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){   
    $color = get_field('title_color');
    if( $color ) {
        echo "<style>.singular .entry-title{ color: $color; }</style>";
    }
}, 11 );
```